# Inheriting liquid-fire transitions from an ember-cli addon

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

From the documentation it says to define animations inside [app/transitions.js](http://ef4.github.io/liquid-fire/#/).  I want to define some common animations in an [ember-cli](http://www.ember-cli.com/) add-on project.  The projects that use this add-on should be able to define extra transitions that are specific to that project.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution, if you add the transitions to the addon namespace in the ember-cli addon project.

/addon-name/addon/transitions.js

```
export default function() {
     //Your common tranistions here
}
```

You can then apply them to the project using the addon.

/your-project/app/transitions.js

```
import boilerplateTransitions from 'addon-name/transitions';

export default function() {
  boilerplateTransitions.apply(this, arguments);

  //Your app transitions here
}
```